# Stop first jquery ui tab from preloading content with ajax

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, jquery-ui-tabs

I currently user jquery ui to create a dialog window that is hidden on page load.  The user opens the dialog by clicking a button.  Once open, the dialog has several tabs (created with jquery ui tabs), each one displaying a form that a user might need access to.  The actual forms are loaded using ajaxOptions.

Is there a way to stop jquery from preloading my first ui tab on page load?  Instead, I want the content of the first tab loaded only when the user clicks the button to open the dialog.

```
    $( "#pref_tabs" ).tabs({
    ajaxOptions: {
        success: function(xhr, status, index, anchor) {
           //function to handle successful loading
        },
        error: function( xhr, status, index, anchor ) {
            $( anchor.hash ).html(
                "Couldn't load this form. We'll try to fix this as soon as possible. ");
        },
    }
});
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Add an additional option to your tabs options to make no tabs selected by default.

```
$(sel).tabs({
    selected: -1,
    ajaxOptions: {...
});
```

Comment: Great.  That did the trick.  I added `$( "#pref_tabs" ).tabs( "option", "selected", 0 );` on the button click event so to trigger the selection of the first tab at that point, which is what I wanted to do.